# Can I alter the behavior of python's return statement?

Tags: python, return, code-inspection

How can I hack into Python's return statement to make it do the extra work of sending some inspection data to a logging module I am writing?

Up until now, I am tacking a function called owl() before every return statement.

```
owl()
return (something)
```

I am hoping I can temporarily sneak the work into the return statement. Then I can turn this return tweak off and on and perhaps also gain some access to see what it is returning.

Comment: unsure exactly what you want but maybe return(owl()) and put it into a dump variable such as Dump = Function(), Dump = "":

Comment: You can use decorators for such cases - https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the function body in a `try/finally` block:

```
def func(...)
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        owl()
```

The `finally:` code is always executed when leaving the block, so it will be executed whenever the function returns.

To avoid having to write this every time, you can use a decorator.

```
def with_owl(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs):
        finally:
            owl()

@with_owl
def func(...):
    ...
```

Comment: Did you mean `finally` instead of `always`?

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. I think a context manager is only needed if you need both setup and cleanup, `finally` is enough for just a single exit action.

Comment: The nice thing about a context manager is that you don't have to explicitly catch the exception; the `__exit__` method will get the exception and let you do anything you want before returning. (I'm mostly thinking how how this looks using the `contextmanager` decorator, though.)

Comment: No exception is being caught.

Answer (score 0):

Define a context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def with_owl():
    yield
    owl()
```

Then

```
def foo():
    with with_owl():
        ...
```

`owl()` will be called just before you exit the `with` statement for *any* reason, whether by reaching the end of the body or leaving early due to a `return` statement or an exception. (The context manager can explicitly check if an exception has been raised, if you only want call `owl()` on a "normal" return.)

Basically, everything before the `yield` statement in `with_owl` executes immediately upon entry to the `with` statement, and just before you leave the `with` statement you return to `with_owl` and execute what comes after the `yield`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought perhaps there was a way to play with the inner workings of "return" itself so that a line of code at the top of the file would infest a new logging functionality throughout my code.

Comment: Context managers are a generalization of this idea. Rather than limiting you to providing "exit" code when you leave a function, you can provide exit code for any block (i.e., the body of the `with` statement) of your choice. For your case, the entire function is just a single `with` statement, with what was the body of the function now the body of the `with` statement.

Comment: Oh wow! I get what you are saying now! It clicked! I am going to dive into this. Thank you to everyone who helped me learn today. Pys be with all of you.

Comment: Thanks chepner. I was trying to do this before you posted and really had not figured it out, but your explanation puts me back on the path.